# How to import data from CSV to HTML

Tags: html, jquery, ajax, csv

I'm trying to follow these instructions [webslesson.info](https://www.webslesson.info/2017/04/csv-file-to-html-table-using-ajax-jquery.html)

index.html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
 <head>
  <title>CSV File to HTML Table Using AJAX jQuery</title>
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css" />
  <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
 </head>
 <body>
  <div class="container">
   <div class="table-responsive">
    <h1 align="center">CSV File to HTML Table Using AJAX jQuery</h1>
    <br />
    <div align="center">
     <button type="button" name="load_data" id="load_data" class="btn btn-info">Load Data</button>
    </div>
    <br />
    <div id="employee_table">
    </div>
   </div>
  </div>
 </body>
</html>

<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
 $('#load_data').click(function(){
  $.ajax({
   url:"employee.csv",
   dataType:"text",
   success:function(data)
   {
    var employee_data = data.split(/\r?\n|\r/);
    var table_data = '<table class="table table-bordered table-striped">';
    for(var count = 0; count<employee_data.length; count++)
    {
     var cell_data = employee_data[count].split(",");
     table_data += '<tr>';
     for(var cell_count=0; cell_count<cell_data.length; cell_count++)
     {
      if(count === 0)
      {
       table_data += '<th>'+cell_data[cell_count]+'</th>';
      }
      else
      {
       table_data += '<td>'+cell_data[cell_count]+'</td>';
      }
     }
     table_data += '</tr>';
    }
    table_data += '</table>';
    $('#employee_table').html(table_data);
   }
  });
 });
 
});
</script>
```

I've put index.html on my pc, in the same folder as my own unique csv file, not the one probided in the tutorial, in the index.html I originally changed employee.csv to my own csv file name, when it didn't work I changed it back and just changed the filename of my csv to employee.csv

But nothing happens when I click on the load data button.

Just looking to display the contents of my csv on my browser with the html file.

Comment: Does AJAX Jquery come installed? Or does it need to be installed via an extention? I'm using firefox.

Comment: Check that you are showing file extensions.  It could be "employee.csv.csv".   Did the original code work before you changed it?

Comment: When you've opened the page and clicked the button, look in the browser console (press F12).  If you have a message like `Access to XMLHttpRequest at 'file: has been blocked by CORS` then you're opening the htm file locally from your compter and need a webserver.  Otherwise it should give a 404 if the file name is incorrect.

Comment: freedomn-m All the files in the folder have their extensions showing, I hadn't tried with the original csv, but I did after you asked, alas, still doesn't work.

Comment: freedomn-m Yes, "Cross-Origin Request Blocked: The Same Origin Policy disallows reading the remote resource at file:///addressl/employee.csv. (Reason: CORS request not http)" I'll try it through a webserver then, thanks.

Comment: Yes, you need a webservice, double clicking an html file to open it directly works for a lot of code, but not for reading `file:///` files

Comment: Seems it won't let me designate the correct answer, but live server then "http://127.0.0.1:5500/index.html" was the answer.

Comment: There's no answer to accept, just comments to get you going.   In this case I'm sure there are 100+ existing answers in SO *once you know where to look* so would get closed as a duplicate. Glad to hear you got it working.

Answer (score 0):

freedomn-m provided the answer, works with a live server